# Como colocar os dados de um while dentro de uma variável?

Tags: php, mysql

Este código me retorna diversos os valores do banco de dados:

```
while($TiV = $frm_interesse->fetch()){    
    echo $TiV['CODIGO'];    
}
```

... e eu preciso mandar estes valores por e-mail com o `PHPMailer`. Preciso de uma ajuda para chegar ao seguinte resultado:

> Você visualizou o imóvel com código 1234
>
> Você visualizou o imóvel com código 5678
>
> Você visualizou o imóvel com código 9012
>
> Você visualizou o imóvel com código 3456

Como eu poderia por exemplo colocar estes valores dentro de uma variável separados por um espaço pra depois dar um explode e fazer o que quiser delas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem um monte de jeito.

Aqui uma em formato texto, para usar por exemplo no corpo de um email:

```
$separador = '';
$codigos = '';
while( $TiV = $frm_interesse->fetch() ) {  
    $codigos .= $separador. $TiV['CODIGO'];
    $separador = ', ';    
}
```

Nessa aqui você nao precisa de `explode`, afinal, se vai usar *array*, já use o tipo certo.

```
$codigos = array();
while( $TiV = $frm_interesse->fetch() ) {  
    $codigos[] = $TiV['CODIGO'];
}

// visualização:
echo implode( ', ', $codigos );
```

Agora, se a saída é exatamente o que está no corpo da pergunta, bastaria isso:

```
$codigos = '';
while( $TiV = $frm_interesse->fetch() ) {  
    $codigos .= 'Você visualizou o imóvel com código '.$TiV['CODIGO'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

(a quebra de linha PHP_EOL você adapta conforme a saída - email, pagina, etc.)

Comment: Não sei se é uma boa pergunta mas como dou um `echo` em `$codigos` dentro do script do `PHPMailer`?

Comment: Não tem que dar echo, você insere a $variavel no corpo do email. `$corpodoemail = "Olá, visitante! " . $codigos;` e aí conforme a documentação do PHPMailer você insere o $corpodoemail no lugar certo. Tem exemplos de uso de PHPMailer aqui no próprio site, basta uma pesquisa rápida.